# TypeError with Quasar q-list

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I have a Vue 3.2.37 project.

I try to create a Quasar (Version 2.7.5) q-list with the following code:

```
<template>
    <q-page>
      <q-list>
        <q-item v-for="(item, index) in dynamicList" :key="index">
          <q-item-section>
            <q-item-label>{{ item.name }}</q-item-label>
            <q-item-label caption>{{ item.description }}</q-item-label>
          </q-item-section>
        </q-item>
      </q-list>
    </q-page>
  </template>
  
  <script>
  export default {
    name: "result-list",
    data() {
      return {
        dynamicList: [
          { name: 'Item 1', description: 'Description for Item 1' },
        ],
      };
    },
  };
  </script>
```

I embed it in another view like this:

```
    <SearchResultList></SearchResultList>
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'header')
at ReactiveEffect.fn (QPage.js?v=5a3b0221:25:20)
at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:185:25)
at get value [as value] (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:1144:39)
at Proxy.<anonymous> (QPage.js?v=5a3b0221:53:20)
at renderComponentRoot (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:896:44)
at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5580:57)
at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:185:25)
at instance.update (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5694:56)
at setupRenderEffect (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5708:9)
at mountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5490:9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution: When I wrap the q-page in a q-layout and the q-list in a div, it works.

```
<q-layout>
    <q-page>
        <div>
            <q-list>
                ...
            </q-list>
        </div>
    </q-page>
</q-layout>
```